# Plot Circles on Line Chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to plot marker of circle shape on a line chart to represent some values from x-axis. Screenshot is attached with details. Thanks!

check this image for what I am looking for

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dataLabels` and `marker` properties:

```
series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        y: 10
    },
    marker: {
        radius: 10,
        fillColor: '#FFF',
        lineColor: '#7cb5ec',
        lineWidth: 2
    }
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n7uhwzk8/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.enabled

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)